# Why css, js do not connect to html in Spring MVC project?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Why styles and js are not connected to the page? When displaying a page, I get an error at these files.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of **404**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sources/css/styles.css">

</head>
<body >
<h1>Hey there</h1>
<a href="/departments">click here</a>

<script src="/sources/scripts/initial_service.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

T**he project structure:**

[image]

**The Web Config:**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller"})
public class WebConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        bean.setSuffix(".html");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/sources/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/image/**").addResourceLocations("/sources/image/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/sources/scripts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/main.html");
    }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: you add the resource handler, but you don't use it. remove `/sources` in your HTML

Comment: Ok, I'll try now

Comment: @PhilippSander
You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this one will reduce your code

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/source/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/source/");
    }
```

Comment: I like this approach more than mine

Comment: @PhilippSander My pleasure !

Comment: @AvijitBarua 
But after changing on the page and in the config, I get the same error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: @VladislavSolopov If you use my code you would not need to change your jsp page. Just keep it as it was. like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sources/css/styles.css">`

Comment: @AvijitBarua I can use: /sources/css/styles.css ? right?

Comment: @AvijitBarua
I understand you, now I will try again. Last time got 404

Comment: Try and let us know

Comment: @AvijitBarua mmm, understand the reason of 404 error. 
please, change to: registry.addResourceHandler("/sources/**").addResourceLocations("/sources/");

Comment: @VladislavSolopov Pleasure buddy !

Answer (score 1):

you add resource handlers but you do not use them. remove `/sources` from the paths where you load your resources.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">

</head>
<body >
<h1>Hey there</h1>
<a href="/departments">click here</a>

<script src="/scripts/initial_service.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```